# Can't long-press ALT or CTRL, only once at a time

Tags: keyboard, maplestory

When I hold any letter key, naturally it keeps typing that key, or when I hold an arrow key in a game it will keep going in that direction.

However, in MapleStory, when I hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, it's supposed to continuously attack and when I hold <kbd>ALT</kbd> it's supposed to continuously jump, but instead, it does the action only once when I hold the key. This happens only with <kbd>ALT</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, I know because when I tried to move the jump action for example to another key and held it, it worked.

This only happens on my Dell 5577 gaming laptop with the built-in keyboard, works on my PC with the external keyboard. Haven't tried connecting an external keyboard to the laptop. I have Windows 10 on it, so maybe it's an issue with some settings?

**The issue here is NOT about simultaneous keypress!** It's about not being able to hold <kbd>ALT</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> ingame and get continuous input. It does work with space and other keys, so I think it's something with the Windows 10 settings/BIOS settings but I couldn't find anyone with a similar problem as mine on Google. Again, it only happens with this laptop.

**EDIT:** Turning on Filter Keys and then turning on "Repeat Keys" to 0.3 seconds on both works as a semi-fix. After turning it on, when I hold <kbd>ALT</kbd>, it jumps every 0.3 seconds. But this isn't a proper fix because now there's a 0.3 second delay when holding ANY key on the keyboard. So now I know that IT IS a problem with Windows 10 and not with my laptop. Still not sure how to properly fix this, waiting for your help guys.

Comment: What is that certain game? I think sometimes these limitations are build into games, to prevent exploit.

Comment: @Joachim Nope, it happens in MapleStory and it's not a game issue. It's designed to be possible and only happens to me with this laptop (Dell 5577 Windows 10)

Comment: Could it have something to do with the Windows 'Sticky Keys' feature (under 'Easy Access Keys'?

Comment: @Joachim I had already checked but sticky keys, toggle keys and filter keys are all off.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about windows 10, and not gaming. Please clarify the question with a specific game, as individual games determine how a held button is interpreted.

Comment: @Gigazelle I'm voting to leave open. OP has mentioned that this is for the game, MapleStory as per their comment. (I've edited the question accordingly.) General Windows solutions might not work for MapleStory specifically or might not work optimally with it. It just so happens that for OP's case, a general Windows solution does work.

Comment: Sounds good. Close vote retracted.

Comment: For what it's worth I, as the user who originally flagged the question for closure, still think it is off-topic.

Comment: We should usually be applying the tech support acid test to these types of questions.  Namely, if you remove the game from the problem, does the problem still exist?  If so, it doesn't belong here.  Considering that mapping keys or using another computer solves the problem in-game, I'm inclined to agree with the off-topic flag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to fix this problem in the following way, for anyone that has the same issue as me.

Go to Windows Settings, and navigate to Filter Keys.
Turn on Filter Keys, and then turn on "Repeat Keys" under it. The minimum value will be 0.3 seconds (300 milliseconds) in both options, but this is changeable on the registry.

Press WIN + R to open the Run prompt, and type "regedit". Press enter.

Go to

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Accessibility\Keyboard Response
```

After playing with the settings for sometime, I was able to mimic the keyboard behavior of my PC with these values:

```
-> Set "AutoRepeatDelay" to 500
-> Set "AutoRepeatRate" to 30
-> Set "BounceTime" and "DelayBeforeAcceptance" to 0
-> Set "Flags" to 59
```

You may then close the registry, and sign out or restart to apply the changes.

I can now hold CTRL, SHIFT or ALT and it will send constant input. I wonder why it didn't work by default like all of my other PCs and laptops, but whatever.